# Flutter app runs perfectly on android studio emulator but doesn't go past the loading screen on physical device

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've created a simple flutter app to tell me the weather using a weather API and the HTTP package. The app runs as intended on my emulated device and for testing, on a physical device, I built a fat apk using `flutter build ask. Unfortunately, the app doesn't go past the loading screen on physical devices(I've tested it on multiple devices).

> android manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="co.appbrewery.clima">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

> loading screen

```
import 'package:clima/services/weather.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'location_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getlocationdata();
  }

  void getlocationdata() async {
    WeatherModel weatherModel = WeatherModel();
    var weatherdata = await weatherModel.getlocationweather();
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return LocationScreen(
        locationweather: weatherdata,
      );
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitChasingDots(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 50,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What's going wrong? I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you run it in debug mode on the physical device?

Comment: Yes I did and it works there. Doesn't work when I install apk on device.

Comment: @YoavGenish  ...

Comment: Maybe it's just a permission problem

Comment: Try to delete the apk on the device abd completely re-install

Comment: @YoavGenish I've done that a lot of times. Tried all the build methods. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can process like that :

Comment the line with `getlocationdata();`
Then run with `flutter run`

If it work, look in debug mode why that doesn't work.
If it still not work, so try to replace the `SpinKitChasingDots` by `Text("test")`.

Good luck